# Removing array entries from lastlog command bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, grep

I am running a command in a script which saves usernames in an array and I was wondering if there is a simple solution to removing these usernames during a run of the lastlog command.

I was thinking of something like this:

```
lastlog | grep -v "Never logged in" | grep -v ${excluded_users} | awk '{print $1,":",$5,$6,$9 }'
```

If it at all works please let me know.

Otherwise I'm open for different suggestions and or solutions.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend your idea, you could put the list of users into a file and do a `... | grep -vwFf excluded_users.txt | ....`.

Perhaps a more robust way to remove the users would be to do it in your awk command:

```
awk '$1 ~! /userA|userB|userC/ {print ... }'
```

Comment: What's the difference between `~!` and `!~`?

Comment: Thank you for input. I like the idea of creating a file first.

Could you elaborate on the second part though. As I understand I would still need to manually add the users that are to be excluded right?

@knittl ~! might be a typo.

Comment: No. In your original solution, you had the users in a shell variable `excluded_users`. Nothing provents you to use such a variable in your awk program (and let the shell expand it) to result in your users list. Furthermore, nothing prevents you to load such a variable from a file. These are different problems though, and in case you get stuck with here, I suggest that you ask a new question for the respective sub-problem.